# Immutable class with reference of mutable class

Tags: java, mutable

Suppose I am creating a immutable class Employee which has has mutable class reference Address. how can we create the immutable class with scenario.

I just refer to this link [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html). I did not understand this point:

> Don't share references to the mutable objects. Never store references
>   to external, mutable objects passed to the constructor; if necessary,
>   create copies, and store references to the copies. Similarly, create
>   copies of your internal mutable objects when necessary to avoid
>   returning the originals in your methods.

Comment: Show a minimal example replicating the situation that you are trying to describe, highlighting the creation of all involved objects, and the situations where you do or do not want mutability.

Comment: Please explain the question properly. Question is not clear

Comment: yes i know this class is not immutable, is possible to make this class immutable ?

Comment: @ashishchaurasia: Yes, a couple of the answers below (including mine) say how to. Is there more information you need?

Comment: @ashishchaurasia: What part don't you understand? If the class is immutable, it can't be made up of mutable parts. The quote you've added to the question says exactly what I said in my answer: Make immutable copies of things if the source information is mutable.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to encapsulate a mutable object into an immutable one, then you need to:

- Create a copy of the mutable object (i.e. via copy constructor, cloning, serialization/deserialization, etc.); never store the reference to the original mutable object.
- Never return the mutable object. If you must to, then return a copy of the object.
- Avoid methods which can change the mutable object

Reference: [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects - The Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not without breaking the `Address` class's contract.

Instead, you can create a new class which I'll call `ImmutableAddress`, and have it accept an `Address` in its constructor and grab relevant information from it, exposing getters for that information, but no setters. (It's important that you don't just store the `Address`; you must grab the information from it and store that, since you can't trust anything not to modify the `Address` you're given). Then use `ImmutableAddress` on `Employee` rather than `Address`.

Now, having said that, the sad fact is that you see class contracts broken fairly regularly with runtime exceptions. The way you'd do that would be to subclass `Address` and make all its setters throw a runtime exception, then constructor your subclass with a reference to a passed-in `Address`. But that's a hack, better to create the new, truly immutable class.

Comment: Thanks. I doubted myself with this. But, with this answer. I am sure of myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an immutable copy of your `Address` class and use that in the `Employee` class. For instance:

```
public final class ImmutableAddress
{
    private final String street;

    public ImmutableAddress(final Addres addr)
    {
        Objects.checkNotNull(addr, "null arguments not accepted");
        street = addr.getStreet();
    }

    // Alternate, static constructor
    public static ImmutableAddress from(final Address addr)
    {
        return new ImmutableAddress(addr);
    }

    public String getStreet() { return street; }
}
```

Then in the constructor of `Employee` you'd do:

```
private final ImmutableAddress addresss;

public Employee(final Address addr)
{
    address = ImmutableAddress.from(addr);
}
```